# tf.experimental.set_loop_options - shape invariants fail with TPU strategy

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tpu

I am trying to run a loop within distributed strategy in tensorflow where a variables keeps on storing the outputs, thus its shape keeps changing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

@tf.function(autograph=True)
def f():
  v = tf.constant((0,))
  for i in tf.range(3):
    tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options(
        shape_invariants=[(v, tf.TensorShape([None]))]
    )
    v = tf.concat((v, [i]), 0)
  return v

strategy.run(f)
```

The code above works fine. But if I replace the strategy by a TPUstrategy, i.e, the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

@tf.function(autograph=True)
def f():
  v = tf.constant((0,))
  for i in tf.range(3):
    tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options(
        shape_invariants=[(v, tf.TensorShape([None]))]
    )
    v = tf.concat((v, [i]), 0)
  return v

strategy.run(f)
```

This code throws an error -

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    697                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    698                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 699             printer.pretty(obj)
    700             printer.flush()
    701             return stream.getvalue()

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in shape(self)
   1325         # `_tensor_shape` is declared and defined in the definition of
   1326         # `EagerTensor`, in C.
-> 1327         self._tensor_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(self._shape_tuple())
   1328       except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
   1329         raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None

InvalidArgumentError: 9 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_230}} Input and output shapes of loop body do not match: (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[1], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[]) vs. (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[2], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[])

     [[{{function_node __inference_f_202}}{{node while}}]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_17449455679645184466/_2]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_230}} Input and output shapes of loop body do not match: (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[1], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[]) vs. (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[2], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[])

     [[{{function_node __inference_f_202}}{{node while}}]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_17449455679645184466/_2]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_5804319525153755267/_3/_35]]
  (2) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_230}} Input and output shapes of loop body do not match: (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[1], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[]) vs. (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[2], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[])

     [[{{function_node __inference_f_202}}{{node while}}]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_17449455679645184466/_2]]
     [[cluster_tpu_function/control_after/_1/_99]]
  (3) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_230}} Input and output shapes of loop body do not match: (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[1], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[]) vs. (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[2], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[])

     [[{{function_node __inference_f_202}}{{node while}}]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_17449455679645184466/_2]]
     [[cluster_tpu_function/control_after/_1/_95]]
  (4) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_230}} Input and output shapes of loop body do not match: (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[1], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[]) vs. (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[2], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[])

     [[{{function_node __inference_f_202}}{{node while}}]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_17449455679645184466/_2]]
     [[cluster_tpu_function/control_after/_1/_91]]
  (5) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_230}} Input and output shapes of loop body do not match: (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[1], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[]) vs. (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[2], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[])

     [[{{function_node __inference_f_202}}{{node while}}]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_17449455679645184466/_2]]
     [[cluster_tpu_function/control_after/_1/_83]]
  (6) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_230}} Input and output shapes of loop body do not match: (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[1], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[]) vs. (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[2], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[])

     [[{{function_node __inference_f_202}}{{node while}}]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_17449455679645184466/_2]]
     [[cluster_tpu_function/control_after/_1/_111]]
  (7) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_230}} Input and output shapes of loop body do not match: (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[1], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[]) vs. (s32[], s32[], s32[], s32[2], s32[], /*index=5*/s32[])

     [[{{function_node __inference_f_202}}{{node while}}]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_174 ... [truncated]
```

Please let me know if there is a way to set shape invariants with TPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow official documentation seems to give a not-very suitable example of using the `shape_invariants` loop parameter, which motivates users to use it as a way to allow them to accumulate intermediate values from a loop into a tensor.

Tensorflow actually has class [tf.TensorArray](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) designed specifically to help to implement such patterns.

Your example with using of `tf.TensorArray` could look something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

@tf.function()
def f():
  v = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=3)
  for i in tf.range(3):
    v = v.write(i, i)
  return v.stack()

strategy.run(f)
```

My output:

```
PerReplica:{
  0: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>,
  1: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>,
  2: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>,
  3: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>,
  4: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>,
  5: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>,
  6: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>,
  7: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>
}
```